# How to deal with incorrectly stated question with answers?

Tags: discussion

### Question-specific part

So there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975896/finding-hamiltonian-paths-with-dijkstras-algorithm).

[The original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16975896/1):

> Can Dijkstra or Bellman-Ford algorithm find all shortest path in an undirected symmetric graph?

[The next version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16975896/2) (a few minutes later, by the original poster):

> Can Dijkstra algorithm find all shortest path in an undirected and symmetric graph?

Coming in at this point (not having seen the first revision), it's admittedly rather vague, but it seemed a lot like OP was wondering whether Dijkstra's algorithm can find **all-pairs shortest paths** in a symmetric graph.

Maybe I should've commented to make sure, but there was already a (3-hour old unanswered) [comment asking for an elaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975896/finding-hamiltonian-paths-with-dijkstras-algorithm/16980955?noredirect=1#comment24524145_16975896).

After answering the presumed all-pairs shortest paths question and 2 other answers addressing an elementary Dijkstra's algorithm question, [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975896/finding-hamiltonian-paths-with-dijkstras-algorithm/16980955?noredirect=1#comment24529463_16980955) indicated that OP may actually have been looking for a **Hamiltonian path**.

### Generic part

In the meantime, the question was edited (not by OP) to reflect OP's comment(s).

In my opinion, the original phrasing was too close to asking something else (which I provided what I believe to be a decent answer for), that it may have been preferred to change the question to reflect what it was close to asking and have OP ask a different better-phrased question, or have someone ask this question on OP's behalf.

What's the correct course of action here (and in general)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to accept the question in the form that best fits the OP's stated intent.  In most cases, that means the OP's latest edit.  Answerers who posted before the clarification are free to update their answer to make it better fit with the OP's current version.

If it is unclear what the intention of the OP is, and no further clarification from the OP is forthcoming, you have two options:

1. Answer the question the best you can given the information provided, or
2. Vote to close as Not a Real Question.

Modifying the question to clarify what the OP's intent *might* be amounts to guessing, and is bad form unless the question has clearly been abandoned by the OP.  Editing the question to clarify what the OP has already stated in comments is, of course, perfectly OK.